# Convert POSIX->WIN path, in Cygwin Python, w/o calling cygpath

Tags: python, cygwin

I use a Python script, running in a Cygwin build of Python, to create commands issued to native Windows utilities (not Cygwin-aware). This requires conversion of path parameters from POSIX to WIN form before issuing the command.

Calling the cygpath utility is the nicest way to do this, since it uses Cygwin to do what it's there to do, but it's also a little horrifying (and slow).

I'm already running a Cygwin build of Python - so the code to do the conversion is present. It seems like there should be a Cygwin/Python specific extension that gives me a hook to this capability, directly in Python, without having to fire up a whole new process.

Comment: I realize the question is for *not* calling cygpath, but for anyone coming from Google: calling cygpath.exe in subprocess.run worked for me in a way none of the answers here did.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible by calling the Cygwin API using ctypes. The below code works for me–I am using 64-bit cygwin DLL version 2.5.2 on Windows 2012, and this works on the Cygwin versions of both Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.4.3.

Basically we call [`cygwin_create_path`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-create-path.html) from `cygwin1.dll` to perform the path conversion. That function allocates a memory buffer (using `malloc`) containing the converted path. So then we need to use `free` from `cygwin1.dll` to release the buffer it allocated.

Note that `xunicode` below is a poor man's alternative to [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) (a Python 2/3 compatibility library); if you need to support both Python 2 and 3, six is the much better answer, but I wanted my example to be free of dependencies on any non-bundled modules which is why I did it this way.

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_void_p, c_int32, cast, c_char_p, c_wchar_p
from sys import version_info

xunicode = str if version_info[0] > 2 else eval("unicode")

# If running under Cygwin Python, just use DLL name
# If running under non-Cygwin Windows Python, use full path to cygwin1.dll
# Note Python and cygwin1.dll must match bitness (i.e. 32-bit Python must
# use 32-bit cygwin1.dll, 64-bit Python must use 64-bit cygwin1.dll.)
cygwin = cdll.LoadLibrary("cygwin1.dll")
cygwin_create_path = cygwin.cygwin_create_path
cygwin_create_path.restype = c_void_p
cygwin_create_path.argtypes = [c_int32, c_void_p]

# Initialise the cygwin DLL. This step should only be done if using
# non-Cygwin Python. If you are using Cygwin Python don't do this because
# it has already been done for you.
cygwin_dll_init = cygwin.cygwin_dll_init
cygwin_dll_init.restype = None
cygwin_dll_init.argtypes = []
cygwin_dll_init()

free = cygwin.free
free.restype = None
free.argtypes = [c_void_p]

CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A = 0
CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W = 1
CCP_WIN_A_TO_POSIX = 2
CCP_WIN_W_TO_POSIX = 3

def win2posix(path):
    """Convert a Windows path to a Cygwin path"""
    result = cygwin_create_path(CCP_WIN_W_TO_POSIX,xunicode(path))
    if result is None:
        raise Exception("cygwin_create_path failed")
    value = cast(result,c_char_p).value
    free(result)
    return value

def posix2win(path):
    """Convert a Cygwin path to a Windows path"""
    result = cygwin_create_path(CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W,str(path))
    if result is None:
        raise Exception("cygwin_create_path failed")
    value = cast(result,c_wchar_p).value
    free(result)
    return value

# Example, convert LOCALAPPDATA to cygwin path and back
from os import environ
localAppData = environ["LOCALAPPDATA"]
print("Original Win32 path: %s" % localAppData)
localAppData = win2posix(localAppData)
print("As a POSIX path: %s" % localAppData)
localAppData = posix2win(localAppData)
print("Back to a Windows path: %s" % localAppData)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the ctypes-code, but I cannot make it run with WinPython-3.5.2 & 2.7.10: 

PY2 crashes on ctypes ``self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)``, and 

PY3 on ``result = cygwin_create_path(CCP_WIN_W_TO_POSIX, xunicode(path))
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000``.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ankostis, I think the problem is likely at the line `cygwin = cdll.LoadLibrary("cygwin1.dll")`. With Cygwin Python, `cygwin1.dll` is already loaded into the Python process address space so `LoadLibrary` has no trouble finding it. However, since WinPython is a pure Windows app (no Cygwin), so `cygwin1.dll` will not normally be loaded, so you need to provide the full path to your `cygwin1.dll`. Also, if your WinPython is 64-bit, you need to load a 64-bit `cygwin1.dll`; conversely, if your WinPython is 32-bit, you need to load a 32-bit `cygwin1.dll`.

Comment: I tried in another machine as you said, and now I'm getting this:
 `Original Win32 path: C:\Users\ankostis\AppData\Local
      0 [main] python 772 D:\Apps\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1\python-3.5.2.amd64\python.exe: *** fatal error - Internal error: TP_NUM_C_BUFS too small: 50
   1090 [main] python 772 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to python.exe.stackdump
@tokoti(cygwin):~/Work/gitdb.git$less python.exe.stackdump`

Comment: @ankostis, I think this is because you need to call `cygwin_dll_init` first. I have updated my answer to include that step. Note that I didn't have to do it originally, since I was using Cygwin Python, and in Cygwin Python the cygwin DLL is already initialised.

Comment: Under Cygwin, you should be able to capture `errno` to get a better exception. Use `cygwin = ctypes.CDLL("cygwin1.dll", use_errno=True)`. Then if the call fails get the value as `errno = ctypes.get_errno()` and then `raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))`. This won't work in Windows Python, since the `errno` value it saves will be for Python's C runtime, not Cygwin.

Comment: Nice. Didn't work for me initially until I did the following modification in posix2win
result = cygwin_create_path(CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W, path.encode('utf8'))

Answer (score 1):

From browsing the [cygpath source](https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/utils/cygpath.cc), it looks like cygpath has a nontrivial implementation and doesn't make any library version available.

cygpath does support taking its input from a file using the `-f` option (or from stdin, using `-f -`) and can take multiple paths, spitting out a converted path each time, so you could probably create a single cygpath instance open (using Python's [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)) rather than restarting cygpath each time.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather write this Python helper that uses the `cygwin` dll:

```
import errno
import ctypes
import enum
import sys

class ccp_what(enum.Enum):
    posix_to_win_a = 0 # from is char *posix, to is char *win32
    posix_to_win_w = 1 # from is char *posix, to is wchar_t *win32
    win_a_to_posix = 2 # from is char *win32, to is char *posix
    win_w_to_posix = 3 # from is wchar_t *win32, to is char *posix

    convtype_mask = 3

    absolute = 0          # Request absolute path (default).
    relative = 0x100      # Request to keep path relative.
    proc_cygdrive = 0x200 # Request to return /proc/cygdrive path (only with CCP_*_TO_POSIX)

class CygpathError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, errno, msg=""):
        self.errno = errno
        super(Exception, self).__init__(os.strerror(errno))

class Cygpath(object):
    bufsize = 512

    def __init__(self):
        if 'cygwin' not in sys.platform:
            raise SystemError('Not running on cygwin')

        self._dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("cygwin1.dll")

    def _cygwin_conv_path(self, what, path, size = None):
        if size is None:
            size = self.bufsize
        out = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
        ret = self._dll.cygwin_conv_path(what, path, out, size)
        if ret < 0:
            raise CygpathError(ctypes.get_errno())
        return out.value

    def posix2win(self, path, relative=False):
        out = ctypes.create_string_buffer(self.bufsize)
        t = ccp_what.relative.value if relative else ccp_what.absolute.value
        what = ccp_what.posix_to_win_a.value | t
        return self._cygwin_conv_path(what, path)

    def win2posix(self, path, relative=False):
        out = ctypes.create_string_buffer(self.bufsize)
        t = ccp_what.relative.value if relative else ccp_what.absolute.value
        what = ccp_what.win_a_to_posix.value | t
        return self._cygwin_conv_path(what, path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem independently recently.
The small and quick solution I came up with is as follows:

```
import os
import re

def win_path(path):
    match = re.match('(/(cygdrive/)?)(.*)', path)
    if not match:
        return path.replace('/', '\\')
    dirs = match.group(3).split('/')
    dirs[0] = f'{dirs[0].upper()}:'
    return '\\'.join(dirs)
```

This works with both cygwin (`/cygdrive/...`) and MinGW (`/...`) style paths (I had to support both) as well as relative paths.

```
l = ['/c/test/path',
     '/cygdrive/c/test/path',
     './test/path',
     '../test/path',
     'C:\Windows\Path',
     '.\Windows\Path',
     '..\Windows\Path']
for i in l:
    print(win_path(i))
```

Produces:

```
C:\test\path
C:\test\path
.\test\path
..\test\path
C:\Windows\Path
.\Windows\Path
..\Windows\Path
```

Comment: Can you update the answer and replace the `f-Strings` usage by the old formatting? i.e.,changing `dirs[0] = f'{dirs[0].upper()}:'` to `dirs[0] = "%s:" % dirs[0].upper()` would allow this to be compatible with Python versions older than `3.6`