# How to get native windows path inside msys python?

Tags: python, msys2

When inside msys2-Python (3.4.3), how am I supposed to get the native windows path of some file from the msys-filesystem?

I want to write a configuration file for a native windows application so the msys path rewriting does not come into account.

There is a solution, but I don't like it, because I have to feed an unknown path into a shell:

```py
path = "/home/user/workspace"
output = subprocess.check_output( 'cmd //c echo ' + path, shell = True )
```

This returns `C:/msys64/home/user/workspace`.

This question is not really a duplicate of [Convert POSIX->WIN path, in Cygwin Python, w/o calling cygpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884268) because it is about *msys2*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884268/convert-posix-win-path-in-cygwin-python-w-o-calling-cygpath

Answer (score 3):

MSYS2 comes with a utility named `cygpath` that you can use.  Run `cygpath -w NAME`.  `cygpath` is a command-line utility in `/usr/bin` that you can run the same way you would run any other command-line utility.  The output will be a Windows-style path corresponding to the NAME argument you passed.

Comment: This is useful for those with cygwin installed, but I don't believe this command is available to msys, per OP's question.

Comment: You don't need to install cygwin.  MSYS2 comes with `/usr/bin/cygpath.exe` in its msys2-runtime package.  It's not totally clear if the OP is using MSYS2 or some other similar system, but the question is tagged "msys2" so I expect MSYS2 users to come here and find my answer useful.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  I also found this on the MSYS1 page: "For any executable not dependent on msys-1.0.dll, MSYS will convert POSIX paths that are used as arguments to Win32 paths".  I'm not sure if it's relevant? http://mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion

Answer (score 2):

Based on this great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471976/5892524 here is the same code rewritten to be used inside msys2.

```py
import ctypes
import sys

xunicode = str if sys.version_info[0] > 2 else eval("unicode")

# If running under Msys2 Python, just use DLL name
# If running under non-Msys2 Windows Python, use full path to msys-2.0.dll
# Note Python and msys-2.0.dll must match bitness (i.e. 32-bit Python must
# use 32-bit msys-2.0.dll, 64-bit Python must use 64-bit msys-2.0.dll.)
msys = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("msys-2.0.dll")
msys_create_path = msys.cygwin_create_path
msys_create_path.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
msys_create_path.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_void_p]

# Initialise the msys DLL. This step should only be done if using
# non-msys Python. If you are using msys Python don't do this because
# it has already been done for you.
if sys.platform != "msys":
    msys_dll_init = msys.msys_dll_init
    msys_dll_init.restype = None
    msys_dll_init.argtypes = []
    msys_dll_init()

free = msys.free
free.restype = None
free.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]

CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A = 0
CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W = 1
CCP_WIN_A_TO_POSIX = 2
CCP_WIN_W_TO_POSIX = 3

def win2posix(path):
    """Convert a Windows path to a msys path"""
    result = msys_create_path(CCP_WIN_W_TO_POSIX, xunicode(path))
    if result is None:
        raise Exception("msys_create_path failed")
    value = ctypes.cast(result, ctypes.c_char_p).value
    free(result)
    return value

def posix2win(path):
    """Convert a msys path to a Windows path"""
    result = msys_create_path(CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W, str(path))
    if result is None:
        raise Exception("msys_create_path failed")
    value = ctypes.cast(result, ctypes.c_wchar_p).value
    free(result)
    return value
```