# How to effectively convert a POSIX path to Windows path with Python in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, path, cygwin

### Problem

Imagine you are writing a Python script which runs on cygwin and calls an external C# executable which requires as input a path.
Assume you cannot change the C# executable in any way.
As you send the path you want to the executable, it rejects all cygwin paths.

So if you pass the path `/cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html` as a POSIX path, it will fail as the executable requires a Windows path like `C:\location\of\file.html`

Example:

`Message location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`
`os.system('./cSharpScript.exe ' + message_location)`

Will result in:

`File for the content (/cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html) not found.`

### Things I've tried so far:

PATH = /cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html

1) `path = PATH.replace('/','\\')`

Result: `File for the content (cygdriveclocationoffile.html) not found.`

2) `path  = os.path.abspath(PATH)`

Result: `File for the content (/cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html) not found.`

- `os.path.realpath` has the same results

I'm probably going in a completely wrong direction with my solutions so far... How would you handle it?

Comment: The Windows path is `r'C:\location\of\file.html'`, where `"/cygdrive/c"` -> `"C:"` and slashes translate to backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd hate to do it manually... Does python have some way of dealing with it?

Comment: Not in the standard library; maybe there's a package for it on PyPI. Or maybe Cygwin has a system function or command-line utility to convert paths.

Comment: Fun fact: Windows itself has to translate "C:" to a name in the caller's local device directory. This is referenced as the magic prefix "\??\", such as "\??\C:\location\of\file.html". It resolves to the caller's logon-session mountpoint directory, "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon session id>", which shadows (in a union) the global mount directory, "\Global??". These contain symbolic links (AKA junctions) with well-known names that target devices that are usually in "\Device". The real NT path is thus something like "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\location\of\file.html". But maybe that's a lie, too...

Comment: Perhaps this article may be helpful. [Convert POSIX->WIN path, in Cygwin Python, w/o calling cygpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10884268/9014308)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Cygwin]: cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html):

> cygpath - Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information
>   ...
>
> ```
> -w, --windows         print Windows form of NAMEs (C:\WINNT)
> ```

Example:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054237800]> cygpath.exe -w /cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html
> C:\location\of\file.html
> ```

Translated into *Python* (**this is a rough version, only for demonstrating purposes**):

> ```
> >>> import subprocess
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> def get_win_path(cyg_path):
> ...     return subprocess.check_output(["cygpath", "-w", cyg_path]).strip(b"\n").decode()
> ...
> >>>
> >>> print(get_win_path("/cygdrive/c/location/of/file.html"))
> C:\location\of\file.html
> ```

Comment: @eryksun: Thx for the tip. Shorter is better! Updated the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm (Though with subprocess.call, obviously). Thanks @CristiFati !