# Activating virtualenv from within Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, syntax-error, virtualenv

I am trying to activate my virtualenv (already existing) using the following python code:

**Test.py**

```
import os, sys
filename = "activate"
exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals)
print(os.system('pwd'))

if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
    print('success')
else:
    print('failed')
```

I then run this script via the terminal:

`python Test.py`

which then produces this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "activate_this.py", line 3, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals)
  File "activate", line 4
    deactivate () {
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

---

I can activate the virtualenv successfully by executing `cd env/bin` and then `source activate`

---

TLDR

Activating virtualenv from python script is throwing a syntax error from within the activate file.

Comment: why not do this properly and activate it from a shell script and then run your python in there? not to mention `activate` is a `sh` script so not sure how you plan to execute it with python

Comment: ^^ somehow I highly doubt that, in all my work experience I have never seen it done once this way, typically you make a `sh` script that activates your env and then runs your python program

Comment: You cannot `compile()` a shell script...

Comment: why are you trying to use compile on a bash script (activate)? apart of that, activate changes env variables of the current env to set the requested python executable and paths - running this from (another?) python executable ([even if it works](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)) seems completely nonsensical - why would you do that?

Comment: ok then you need to [make a system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python), probably `source activate.sh` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate a virtualenv with a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+python+script

Comment: @phd my post is activating a virtualenv from within a python script

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very 1<sup>st</sup> line of *activate* (note that *VEnv* is installed on *Win*, but this shouldn't be a problem):

```sh
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
```

That, and the lines below should tell you that *activate* is a (*Bourne*) ***shell*** file.

[[Python 3]: **compile**(*source, filename, mode, flags=0, dont_inherit=False, optimize=-1*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) on the other hand, works with ***Python*** source code.

So, in order to execute the file, you'd need to use other ways, e.g. [[Python 3]: subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). 
You can check how I've used it: [[SO]: How to effectively convert a POSIX path to Windows path with Python in Cygwin? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237800/how-to-effectively-convert-a-posix-path-to-windows-path-with-python-in-cygwin/54240102#54240102).

But, **I really don't see the point of doing all this**, you probably misunderstood your colleague's suggestion. 
Also note that even if you do manage to do it this way, all **the environment variables will only be set in the calling process**, so it will pretty much be unusable (well, unless you also execute your script from there too).

You should go the recommended way ([[PyPA]: Virtualenv - User Guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#user-guide)), and that is (from ***bash***):

```sh
source /path/to/Django/ENV/bin/activate
python your_project_startup_script.py  # (as I recall, it's manage.py)
```

Comment: I'll do it all via the bash script as that is the most logical way

Comment: Yes, no reason not to go with the recommended way, unless some restriction is being imposed.