# How to run a source from python?

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I am trying to run activate.sh file to set environment paths for vitrual environment from python but I am not able to run source files from python. Is there any way to do that

My source is here

```
if sys.argv[1]=='-a':
        os.system('. activate.sh')
    elif sys.argv[1]=='-d':
        os.system('. deactivate.sh')
    else:
        print('You only have -a, -d as options')
```

Comment: Any reason not to run activate.sh **normally** (from *shell*)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420483/activating-virtualenv-from-within-python-script/54420696#54420696

Comment: I am working on something in which I need to automate this from python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess, which will run the bash script. But be careful, only use trusted bash files. So the code should be:

```
import subprocess
if sys.argv[1]=='-a':
        subprocess.call("activate.sh", shell=True)
    elif sys.argv[1]=='-d':
        subprocess.call("deactivate.sh", shell=True)
    else:
        print('You only have -a, -d as options')
```

Comment: the activate and deactivate scripts are in the same folder for which I don't want to set path manually. Also by setting the path I am getting Permission Denied

Comment: This should use the same directory where the script is

Comment: Permission Denied is all I am getting `/bin/sh: 1: ./activate.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: set the bash file permission with chmod to 777 so anyone (including python) can read, write and execute it.

Comment: Even if I make this executable the virtual environment run in the background and closes

Answer (score 0):

This will activate the `virtualenv` on a new bash session.

Assuming things like `platform: linux`, `new bash session` is `OK`.

```
import os
# os.execv("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "source ve/bin/activate;bash"])
os.execv("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "source /path/to/activate;bash"])
```

Comment: I have tried this but the virtual enviroment terminal runs in the background and stops